# Installing WinXP on a vista-equipped laptop [dual-boot(?)]

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, installation

Ok, so I'm new to this. What I want is to install Windows XP on my vista-equipped laptop (dual-boot, if that's what it's called). I have no idea what to do and where to begin. Can someone help me? :) I just want to try Windows XP because of Litestep(the vista version is still on alpha stage) and it uses far less resources than vista (I've only got 1GB RAM). Hope somebody can help me. :)

Comment: This not a direct answer, but once it is available I would suggest considering going to Windows 7. In the meantime, John T's answer is good.

Comment: I'm actually planning to buy a Win7-equipped laptop when it becomes available. But for the meantime, I want to "try" other OS on my old laptop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://apcmag.com/how_to_dual_boot_vista_and_xp_with_vista_installed_first__the_stepbystep_guide.htm) in-depth guide can explain it far better than I can, but in summary:

- Partition the drive
- Install XP
- Fix the Vista bootloader
- Use EasyBCD or bcdedit.exe to modify the boot configuration

Comment: Okay so I saw the tutorial, and frankly it's more complicated than what I expected, lol. 
I've got another problem (I must be so stupid by not thinking of this in the first place, sorry)- I don't have any WinXP installer and I don't want fakes or pirates :(
And I've got another- I tried to make a partition on my Drive C (more than 50 GB available) but then for some reason it only allowed me to shrink 8 MB. I've experience this problem before and I never have it solved. :(

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have any WinXP installer and I
>   don't want fakes or pirates

1. upgrade your system memory, 1 GB is barely entry level specification for Vista or Windows 7.
2. download a [Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Image](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en)
3. use the VPC image with [MS Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=04D26402-3199-48A3-AFA2-2DC0B40A73B6&displaylang=en) or [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and legally enjoy the benefits of Windows XP for free.

note: your version of Vista may not qualify for MS VPC, no such limitations with VirtualBox.

p.s.: the activation of the current VPC images will expire at the end of this month, but there will be new releases then.

Comment: What's the difference of between dual-booting WinXP/Vista and using VirtualBOX? 

PS. I can't upgrade my RAM because this PC is shared- meaning its not entirely mine so I don't want to spend money on it because its not entirely mine.

Comment: with dual boot you can choose the operating system you wish to use at the system start (from a boot manager). a virtual computer allows you to run multiple operating systems simultaneously (Windows guests in seamless mode with VBox).

however, since this is "not entirel"y your computer, if i were you, i'd be very careful with partitioning the drive and setting up a boot manager. i strongly recommended to create a drive image before you proceed.

Comment: What the heck is drive image and how do I create one?
I've read somewhere that I need to add more RAM to use WinXP using VBox, does that mean that I can't use it? (Because I have inadequate RAM)

Cheers :)

Comment: a drive image is a form of backup, it allows to restore the computer to the exact state it was in when the image was taken. and no, 1 GB RAM is not enough to use additional operating systems efficiently in a virtual computer on a Vista host.

Comment: Oh I see, too bad I have inadequate RAM :( 

So, I think I'll just stop myself for wanting a Windows XP then, lol 

Err, I have  a bit off-topic question:
I recently stumbled at the homepage of Ubuntu and some says that its a good OS and I saw a video of the eye-candy on ytube. My question is, how does it stack-up against Windows Vista? Or Windows XP? I might want to try this OS because it has way too low system requirements and....  it's FREE!!! xD



Cheers :)

Comment: OK, so I tried ubuntu and I already kinda like it, everything was just smooth. :) The only thing I don't like is how very complicated finding/installing a software is, but other than that, its good :)

So, I guess I'm done here already as I won't install Windows XP anymore (because I don't have one) xD